# I am getting error after uploading my Laravel project to server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting this error after uploading my laravel project to the server. I have searched this error multiple times but not get some specific answer. I am using laravel 5.5 and PHP version 7.1.

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\json_encode() in
>   /home/cp959319p17/public_html/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/HtmlDumper.php:131

Comment: Do you have the `json` extension installed in your PHP?

Comment: I have no idea, but i have only selected PHP version 7.1 in my cpanel

Comment: or can you help me how to install json extension?

Comment: can you share some video or article line for help?

Answer (score 0):

install json plugin for `php < 5.2.0`

`apt install php-json`

or

`yum install php-json`

As of PHP 5.2.0, the JSON extension is bundled and compiled into PHP by default.

http://php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php

Comment: but how I can install php-json, can you share some video or article  link

Comment: create a php file and use `json-encod()` function. if error occured contact to cpanel admin

Comment: where to create php file in laravel project?

Comment: just upload single php file.